# Folium map when used with PySide2 QWebEngineView, doesn't display basemap

Tags: python, pyqt5, openstreetmap, pyside2, folium

**Overview:** I have a GUI built with PySide2/PyQt5 and using QWebEngineView, I am able to display folium-generated maps, saved to an html and then displayed in the QWebEngineView widgets.

**Problem:** Up until this week, maps displayed showing overlaying icons on top of a basemap. As pictured below.

[image]

Now, maps do not display a basemap and will instead, only show the icons, as shown below.
[image]

If I choose a different source as a basemap, such as MapBox, it works fine. Additionally, if I open up the folium-generated html in a normal web browser, it displays a basemap correctly.

**What I've tried:** I updated PySide2 and folium yesterday, but it had no effect or change to the outcome.

Here's some sample code to try for yourself. I've included the html as text and there's no way to really simplify that much, so I'm sorry that's so much text.

```
import os
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLineEdit, QMainWindow, QToolBar
from PySide2.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

placeholder_html = r"""<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>    
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    
        <script>
            L_NO_TOUCH = false;
            L_DISABLE_3D = false;
        </script>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0.2/leaflet.awesome-markers.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0.2/leaflet.awesome-markers.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawcdn.githack.com/python-visualization/folium/master/folium/templates/leaflet.awesome.rotate.css"/>
    <style>html, body {width: 100%;height: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;}</style>
    <style>#map {position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;right:0;left:0;}</style>
    
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
                initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
            <style>
                #map_305dcca754af4fd68c9ec8c6f4d22187 {
                    position: relative;
                    width: 100.0%;
                    height: 100.0%;
                    left: 0.0%;
                    top: 0.0%;
                }
            </style>
        
    <script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/ljagis/leaflet-measure/2.1.7/dist/leaflet-measure.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawcdn.githack.com/ljagis/leaflet-measure/2.1.7/dist/leaflet-measure.css"/>
</head>
<body>    
    
            <div class="folium-map" id="map_305dcca754af4fd68c9ec8c6f4d22187" ></div>
        
</body>
<script>    
    
            var map_305dcca754af4fd68c9ec8c6f4d22187 = L.map(
                "map_305dcca754af4fd68c9ec8c6f4d22187",
                {
                    center: [37.97388131, -122.0443919],
                    crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857,
                    zoom: 12,
                    zoomControl: true,
                    preferCanvas: false,
                }
            );

            

        
    
            var tile_layer_a14f036f31594845b89380be31bb09fd = L.tileLayer(
                "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                {"attribution": "Data by \u0026copy; \u003ca href=\"http://openstreetmap.org\"\u003eOpenStreetMap\u003c/a\u003e, under \u003ca href=\"http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright\"\u003eODbL\u003c/a\u003e.", "detectRetina": false, "maxNativeZoom": 18, "maxZoom": 18, "minZoom": 0, "noWrap": false, "opacity": 1, "subdomains": "abc", "tms": false}
            ).addTo(map_305dcca754af4fd68c9ec8c6f4d22187);
        
    
            var feature_group_093f66692993484ba636a59ef8052169 = L.featureGroup(
                {}
            ).addTo(map_305dcca754af4fd68c9ec8c6f4d22187);
        
    
            var marker_dd85fc86d67445dfb4f4c435187f91e0 = L.marker(
                [37.97388131, -122.0443919],
                {}
            ).addTo(feature_group_093f66692993484ba636a59ef8052169);
        
    
        marker_dd85fc86d67445dfb4f4c435187f91e0.setIcon(custom_icon_1ef21e7003ac401183c880dcbdb0e61c);
        
    
        var popup_98cc02d3036844c097ff39167bd52667 = L.popup({"maxWidth": "100%"});

        
            var html_a1239c595b2e4c07a7035181d7dce41a = $(`<div id="html_a1239c595b2e4c07a7035181d7dce41a" style="width: 100.0%; height: 100.0%;">WW-01</div>`)[0];
            popup_98cc02d3036844c097ff39167bd52667.setContent(html_a1239c595b2e4c07a7035181d7dce41a);
        

        marker_dd85fc86d67445dfb4f4c435187f91e0.bindPopup(popup_98cc02d3036844c097ff39167bd52667)
        ;

        
    
    
            var measure_control_757d1e5bfbe34cfb8f6e311097138e29 = new L.Control.Measure(
                {"position": "topright", "primaryAreaUnit": "sqmeters", "primaryLengthUnit": "meters", "secondaryAreaUnit": "acres", "secondaryLengthUnit": "miles"});
            map_305dcca754af4fd68c9ec8c6f4d22187.addControl(measure_control_757d1e5bfbe34cfb8f6e311097138e29);

        
    
            var layer_control_38ec13a480454bf98e94d88f44f11118 = {
                base_layers : {
                    "openstreetmap" : tile_layer_a14f036f31594845b89380be31bb09fd,
                },
                overlays :  {
                    "WW-01" : feature_group_093f66692993484ba636a59ef8052169,
                },
            };
            L.control.layers(
                layer_control_38ec13a480454bf98e94d88f44f11118.base_layers,
                layer_control_38ec13a480454bf98e94d88f44f11118.overlays,
                {"autoZIndex": true, "collapsed": true, "position": "topright"}
            ).addTo(map_305dcca754af4fd68c9ec8c6f4d22187);
        
</script>"""

with open('placeholder.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(placeholder_html)

class Browser(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Browser, self).__init__()
        current_path = os.getcwd()
        filepath = '%s%s' % (current_path, '\\placeholder.html')
        filepath = filepath.replace('\\', '/')
        url = r'file:///' + filepath        
        self.toolbar = QToolBar()
        self.addToolBar(self.toolbar)
        self.address = QLineEdit()
        self.address.setText(url)
        self.address.returnPressed.connect(self.load)
        self.toolbar.addWidget(self.address)
        self.view = QWebEngineView()
        self.view.load(QUrl(url))
        self.view.page().urlChanged.connect(self.url_changed)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

    def load(self):
        url = QUrl.fromUserInput(self.address.text())
        if url.isValid():
            self.view.load(url)

    def url_changed(self, url):
        self.address.setText(url.toString())

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = Browser()
main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Perhaps I just need to update something else that I haven't thought of, or maybe OpenStreetMap doesn't work anymore. I'll try some other things in the meantime, but if anyone can spot where I may be going wrong, or if they know something that has changed with one of these packages I'm using, your help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Copy the class Interceptor from my answer in duplicate question and then add  `self.interceptor = Interceptor()` `self.view.page().profile().setUrlRequestInterceptor(self.interceptor)
`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Odd that this functionality wasn't an issue before.